Fail to apply plugin 'com.google.protobuf'
Could someone tell me what I may be doing wrong here, I am getting the following error:

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.google.protobuf', version: '0.8.13', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:


Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.protobuf:com.google.protobuf.gradle.plugin:0.8.13')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository
MavenRepo
Google
maven(https://jitpack.io)
maven2(https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/)

This is my build.gradle script, it is from TorchServe repository, the original was giving me this error too so I tried different things but it is still happening:
buildscript {
  ext {
    spotbugsVersion = '4.0.2'
    toolVersion = '4.0.2'
  }
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.13' apply false
    id 'idea'
    id 'com.github.spotbugs' version '6.0.7' apply false
    id 'com.gradle.enterprise' version '3.14.1' apply false  // Example of adding the missing plugin

}

allprojects {
    version = '1.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io")}
        maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") } // Ensure this line is present

    }

    apply plugin: 'idea'
    idea {
        module {
            outputDir = file('build/classes/java/main')
            testOutputDir = file('build/classes/java/test')
        }
    }
}


def javaProjects() {
    return subprojects.findAll();
}

configure(javaProjects()) {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    defaultTasks 'jar'

    apply from: file("${rootProject.projectDir}/tools/gradle/formatter.gradle")
    apply from: file("${rootProject.projectDir}/tools/gradle/check.gradle")
    apply from: file("${rootProject.projectDir}/tools/gradle/spotbugs.gradle")

    test {
        useTestNG() {
            suites 'testng.xml'
        }

        testLogging {
            showStandardStreams = true
            events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        }
    }
    test.finalizedBy(project.tasks.jacocoTestReport)

    compileJava {
        options.compilerArgs << "-proc:none" << "-Xlint:all,-options,-static" << "-Werror"
    }

    jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
        violationRules {
            rule {
                limit {
                    minimum = 0.70
                }
            }
            afterEvaluate {
                classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                    fileTree(dir: "${rootProject.projectDir}/server/src/main/java",
                            exclude: ['org/pytorch/serve/grpc**/**'])
                }))
            }
        }
    }
}

... and this is my settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal() 
        mavenCentral()       
        google()             
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io")}
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" } // Explicitly add this repository
    }
}



include 'server',
    'archive'

I have read other posts with similar issue and have tried different things but still keep getting the same error.

did you add classpath under project level gradle? If not add the below line
dependencies {
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.13'
}
